# What happens if a kubernetes Service fails?

Tags: kubernetes

I just learned about ReplicaSets and Services in Kubernetes. I know the concept of desired state in ReplicaSets, it means that if one of our pods goes down, it will be rescheduled to keep the number of replicas as desired.

But what happens if a Service goes down/fails? Is there any recovery for that?

Comment: good question i was just wondering the same thing

Answer (score 2):

> A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them - sometimes called a micro-service. The set of Pods targeted by a Service is (usually) determined by a Label Selector (see below for why you might want a Service without a selector). [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

k8s service is a **abstract idea**  it does not consume any cpu/memory as **pod** does, so it does not make sense if it goes down. If you delete it then its deleted, there is no concrete object which is active.

one of the functionally is to provide static IP (cluster IP) and DNS record  so other pods can communicate with it, inter cluster communication. [DNS record](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records)

One of the main responsibilities of kube-proxy is to write the iptables rules which implement Services. Nodes are having same iptables rules which are synchronized by kube-proxy.

Comment: Then what is that "concrete object" that you are referring to? For example it can do load balancing, what if that load balancer goes down?

Comment: service is managed by kube-proxy component which are IPTables rules, which is sync with other nodes.  If kube-proxy goes down, it need to be restarted, it is similar to the kubelet, what if kubelet goes down

Comment: As I understand concrete objects are node, pod as they consume resources, if node goes down, there is nothing we can do, thus we need to have more nodes, if a pod goes down, replicaset is there to reconcile it